# What is the difference between withTest1($a) and compact($a) in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm practicing in Laravel and I've found a useful method "->withVariable($example)" where you can use the Variable as $variable name in the blade file.

> **I would like to ask if there is any difference between method A and method B?**

---

### METHOD A

in controller:

```
$a = 'test a';
$b = 'test b';
$c = 'test c';

return view('welcome')->withTest1($a)->withTest2($b)->withTest3($c);
```

in view:

```
$test1 // test a
$test2 // test b
$test3 // test c
```

---

### METHOD B

in controller:

```
$a = 'test a';
$b = 'test b';
$c = 'test c';

return view('welcome', compact('a', 'b', 'c'));
```

in view:

```
$a // test a
$b // test b
$c // test c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there exists some nasty code which allows for this behaviour, see `Illuminate\View\View`:

```php
    /**
     * Dynamically bind parameters to the view.
     *
     * @param  string  $method
     * @param  array  $parameters
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     *
     * @throws \BadMethodCallException
     */
    public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        if (static::hasMacro($method)) {
            return $this->macroCall($method, $parameters);
        }

        if (! Str::startsWith($method, 'with')) {
            throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
                'Method %s::%s does not exist.', static::class, $method
            ));
        }

        return $this->with(Str::camel(substr($method, 4)), $parameters[0]);
    }
```

So this `__call` method captures all method calls to the view instance.
Calling `view()->withTest('abc')` would result in `$method = 'withTest'` and ultimately cascades down to the last line which just calls `$this->with('test', 'abc')`.

So there is no difference on the end result. The `withTest` chain is just looks nasty.

Imho these magic methods should be avoided; either use the `compact()` form like you already did, or simply use:

```php
view('myview', [
    'foo' => 123,
    'bar' => 'abc'
]);
// or
view('myview')->with([
    'foo' => 123,
    'bar' => 'abc'
]);
// or
$foo = 123;
$bar = 'abc';
view('myview', compact('foo', 'bar'));
// or
view('myview')->with(compact('foo', 'bar'));
```

Sadly there is a range of possibilities.

Comment: Thank you very much. I keep the phrase "these magic methods should be avoided". :)